# не находит xpath и не вводит в поле ввода

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

teleph = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="phone"]')
teleph.send_keys("9211234567")
```

ошибка:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element:  Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="phone"]"}

не ищет `xpath` также пробовал `class` и `id`.

lamoda.ru/p/rtlaan778401/shoes-adidasoriginals-kedy нажимаем добавить в корзину, выбираем любой размер, дальше перейти в корзину и там будет номер телефона, вот это поле ввода надо заполнить

HTML код

```
<input id="phone" name="Телефон" aria-label="Номер телефона" autocomplete="tel" placeholder="" class="input__input" type="tel">
```

Comment: Попробуй поставить задержку что б страница прогрузилась `(time.sleep(5))`, а потом ищи

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="phone"]"} всеравно такая ошибка

Comment: Перечитал вопрос.
Нужно сказать драйверу делать те же последовательные действия, что и при обычном использовании.

1) Тыкнуть размер
2) Открыть корзину
3) Найти там этот xpath.

Конечно не может найти. Потому что этот путь на другой странице.

Comment: так  сам код тыкнуть размер и добавить в корзину написан и работает отлично,но вот текст не получается заполнить

Comment: Значит вопрос изначально не правильно задан.

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)

driver.get('https://lamoda.ru/p/rtlaan778401/shoes-adidasoriginals-kedy')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vue-root"]/x-app-content/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/button').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vue-root"]/x-app-content/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="phone"]').send_keys('+79211234567')
```

- Python 3.7.3
- selenium  3.141.0
- Chrome 92.0.4515.107 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)

видео - https://radikal.ru/video/G18sdHzqnJi

Comment: при использовании версии Chrome 92.0.4515.107 и selenium 4.0.0b4 ошибка как у автора - _Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="phone"]"}_, после обновления Chrome до 92.0.4515.131 ошибок нет